# VB.net prgram with a COM control runs on Windows 7 but not 10

Tags: vb.net, debugging, com, windows-10, ocx

I have a VB.net 2013 program compiled on a Windows 7 machine. The executable will not run on Windows 10. The application references a third-party COM component. I have an old VB6 program that uses the same component that runs fine on Windows 10 so I know that the .ocx file is registered.The event log shows the following error:

Faulting application name: TestOCX.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x5b065e47
Faulting module name: unknown, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x00000000
Exception code: 0xc00001a5
Fault offset: 0x079b32a0
Faulting process id: 0xb4
Faulting application start time: 0x01d3f332b4651dda
Faulting application path: C:\Users\Val Macduff\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\P44NCGBZ.EOJ\ONNATDJR.36P\test..tion_40667f0699a0b5ed_0001.0000_8fc40dff6b9f71d7\TestOCX.exe
Faulting module path: unknown
Report Id: 3be87708-a4c1-4166-90bc-680be71ed4bc
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:

Followed by an Application failed to start error: 0xc0000005

The TestOCX program has a single form with the one COM control on it.

My question is: what is the best way to find out why this program won't run.

Comment: Hallo, Does the executable run fine on Win 7 ?

Comment: Google "0xc00001a5" to find out that the odds you'll ever get this to work properly on Win10 are slim to none.  Only real way ahead is to replace this control.

Comment: I have reinstalled the control and it works with the old VB6 program so why not with a vb.net program. I cannot replace the control as it comes from a piece of third-party software that I cannot duplicate.